# Date functions with leap years

Tags: javascript

I thought by using getTimezoneOffset leap years would be catered for

```
export const dateToDays = async (date: string): Promise<number | null> => {
  if (date === "") return null;
  const now: Date = new Date(date);
  const start: Date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff =
    +now -
    +start +
    (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  if (!day) return null;
  return Number(day);
};
```

but when I run a test for the 29th of Feb 1960 (not a leap year, there is only 28 days in Feb) I expected it to return null

```
test("Test Leap 1961", async () => {
  expect(await dateToDays("1961-02-29")).toEqual(null); // 61
});
```

there also isn't 30 days in Feb 1960

```
test("Test Leap 1960", async () => {
  expect(await dateToDays("1960-02-30")).toEqual(null); // 60
});
```

How can I ensure the above 2 tests return null? or put another way how to make the function return null if a day that doesn't exist is requested?

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: 1960 was a leap year. Also, `new Date("1960-02-30")` returns `1960-03-01T00:00:00.000Z` so March 1st.

Comment: yes 1960 was a leap year but there weren't 30 days in Feb

Comment: But in certain implementations the Date constructor rolls over to the next month. You could check the `getDate()` value of the new Date against the passed day and return null if they don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the validation only checks for `1 <= month <= 12` and `1 <= day <= 31` you will have to check if the parsed month `now.getMonth()+1` (`+1` because it stats at `0`) is the same as the month which has been given to the function via `date`

You accomplish this by the following line:

```
if (parseInt(date.split('-')[1]) !== now.getMonth()+1) return null;
```

```js
const dateToDays = function(date) {
  if (date === "") return null;
  if (isNaN(new Date(date).getDate())) return null;
  const now = new Date(date);
  const start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff =
    +now -
    +start +
    (start.getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000;
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  const day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
  if (!day) return null;

  // check if month is still the same
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------
  if (parseInt(date.split('-')[1]) !== now.getMonth()+1) return null;
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------

  return Number(day);
};

console.log(dateToDays('1960-2-28')); // Ok
console.log(dateToDays('1960-2-29')); // Ok
console.log(dateToDays('1961-2-29')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('1960-2-30')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('1960-2-31')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('1960-4-31')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('1960-2-31')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('1960-13-1')); // Fail
console.log(dateToDays('Hello :)')); // Fail
```

You may want to add a check if the given `date` is actually a valid date-string:

```
if(isNaN(new Date(date).getDate())) return null;
```

Comment: `new Date` doesn't return null, it returns a Date object with a `valueOf()` NaN, or `toString()` value of 'Invalid Date`

Comment: Added the case, thx for the suggestion @pilchard

Comment: `date.split('-')` limits input date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Indeed @FilipSeman but ill leave the refining up to OP

Answer (score -1):

Update first condition.

```js
if (date === "" || isMonthOwerflow(date)) {
    return null;
}

...
```

Example `new Date("1960-02-x")` where x can be `1` to `31` for every month. If the day does not exist, it will owerflow to next month.

---

If you can use libraries, then I recommend `MomentJs`, it's pretty much an industry standard for date-related tasks.

```js
console.log(moment().diff(moment('1960-02-28'), 'years')); // ok, 60
console.log(moment().diff(moment('1960-02-29'), 'years')); // ok, 60
console.log(moment().diff(moment('1960-02-30'), 'years')); // NaN
console.log(moment().diff(moment('1961-02-28'), 'years')); // ok, 59
console.log(moment().diff(moment('1961-02-29'), 'years')); // NaN
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `new Date()` returns a valid date, rolled over to the next month for any days up to 31 in Chrome and Node.